# echo $string does not print array elements while string returned by a function

Tags: php, arrays, string

How to get this

```
    function render($string, $array)
    {
        $pattern = '/[^{{=]*[\w][}}$]/';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

        foreach($matches as $tt)
        {
            $index = '';
            foreach($tt as $match1){
                $match = str_replace('}', '', $match1);

                if (strpos($match,'.') !== false)
                {
                    $string_parts = explode('.', $match);
                    //print_r($string_parts);
                    foreach($string_parts as $part)
                    {
                        $index .="['".$part."']"; 
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    $index ="['".$match."']";
                }
                //echo '$array'.$index;
                $new_str =  str_replace("{{=".$match."}}", '{$array'.$index.'}' , $string);
                    $index = '';
                //echo $new_str;
                $string = $new_str;
            }

        }
        return $string;
    }


    $arr = [
            'site'=>'smartprix',
            'users'=>[
                        ['name'=>'user1', 'contact'=>'1234'],
                        ['name'=>'user2', 'contect'=>'4321']
                     ],
            'location'=>['address'=>['pincode'=>'123456', 'city'=>'Noida'],
                         'near'=>'mamura']
            ];

    $array = $arr;
    //echo "{$array['site']}"; //It is printing smartprix
    $string = "{{=site}} is located at pincode {{=location.address.pincode}}";

    echo render($string, $array);
```

// it is printing "{$array['site']} is located at pincode {$array['location']['address']['pincode']}" why it not convert $array['site'] into the value. I read on php manual and got some reference that {} do not work on returned string then what is the method so that i can print array values after returning the string ?

Comment: Why the `c` and `javascript` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print your expected string is.

```
 echo $string = $array['site']." is located at pincode ".$arr['location']['address']['pincode'];
```